# Pandas Data frames calculating percentage of inexes= same value in a colum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have parsed a large .csv file into a master dataframe. Then I organized the data into 4 different data frames by organizing based on the argument in one of the columns.

is there a way to use a break down to find percentage of indexes in the dataframe that all have the same value for column x.

I can see the raw data such as how many indexes are culled when I organize now want to calculate the percentage

Comment: a combination of `value_counts` and `sum` might help, but  the question is not very concrete

Answer (score 0):

Example to find the percentage of A,B,C in the Customers column

```
df

    Date        Customers   Location    Sales   Service
2   2021-10-01  C           NSW         33      hello1
3   2021-10-05  A           NSW         12      hello3
5   2021-10-01  C           NSW         33      red_i
6   2021-10-05  A           NSW         12      harvest
8   2021-10-01  C           NSW         33      red_i
9   2021-10-05  A           NSW         12      harvest
10  2021-10-03  B           NSW         10      http_2873
11  2021-10-01  C           NSW         33      red_i

df['Customers'].value_counts(normalize=True)

C    0.500
A    0.375
B    0.125
Name: Customers, dtype: float64
```